# Telerik RadGrid OnRowSelected Events, all done event for multiple selection?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a RadGrid with multiple select enabled:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowMultiRowSelection="true">
    <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Dialog" HeaderText="Dialog" DataType="System.String" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelected"/>
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And the OnRowSelected event triggers for each row selected. When selecting 10 rows, the event gets fired 10 times. Simple enough.

My question is what event can I listen to to know when all the rows that are going to be selected are selected (as a result of the multiple selection)? I need to make a post request with the ids of the selected rows and I don't think it's a good idea to let 10 post request be made. I can query the grid to get the selected rows, I just need to know when to do it; ideally something that doesn't involve timeouts. There must an event for this that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got something working with timeouts:

```
var rowSelectedTimeout;

function RowSelected(rowObject) {
    if (window.rowSelectedTimeout) {
        // If selecting multiple rows, clear the previous row's rowSelectedTimeout
        window.clearTimeout(window.rowSelectedTimeout);
    }

    rowSelectedTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.rowSelectedTimeout = null;

        alert('rows selected');
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is really how to figure out when the user has "stopped" selecting. If the multiple selection is done via a shift+click then sure, you have a lot of items to go through, but what if you have the same number of items (10) and the user ctrl+clicks each one of them? It can very easily become a bit over-complicated. There unfortunately isn't an event in the RadGrid that you can subscribe to that triggers after a multiple select action has finished selecting all rows.

Your best option here would probably be to have an external button or something similar that would trigger this post, and then use the SelectedItems collection of the RadGrid since this would then allow for a more batch approach instead of posts occurring for every row.

Comment: Thanks @Carl B. There are a lot of what-ifs, but I would have though Telerik's RadGrid would be sophisticated enough to interpret this. In the case of Shift-click, ideally it should be one event and lets the arguments give an array of selected rows. Or have an additional event, OnShiftClickCompleted. Maybe I can tap into the click events. Hmm..

Comment: No such luck. There is a RowClick event, but I would need a click up instead of click down as it appears to work.